# Is there anyway to get TextMate to display a context menu / tooltip for methods inline for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, textmate

I'm used to eclipse but recently got turned on to TextMate, I like how light it is, but I miss having context menus appear automatically as soon as I type in a "." on an object.

Also, it would be great to have method and class definitions appear as a tool tip, instead of a pop-up.

Is this possible in TextMate?

Comment: Not really; it's nothing like an IDE. You might consider Sublime Text 2; I switch between that and IntelliJ for most of my editing now.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Bundle_for_TextMate